# How to check with PHP if the script is being run from the console or browser request?

Tags: php, shell, console, command-line-interface

I tried things like $_ENV['CLIENTNAME'] == 'Console' but that seems to work on only certain OS's (worked in windows, not linux).

I tried !empty($_ENV['SHELL']) but that doesn't work always either...

Is there a way to check this that will work in all OS's/environments?

Comment: Dupe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607373/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-a-php-script-is-running-in-cli-mode

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use [`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/php_sapi_name)

> Returns a lowercase string that
> describes the type of interface (the
> Server API, SAPI) that PHP is using.
> For example, in CLI PHP this string
> will be "cli" whereas with Apache it
> may have several different values
> depending on the exact SAPI used.

For example:

```
$isCLI = (php_sapi_name() == 'cli');
```

You can also use the constant `PHP_SAPI`

Answer (score 17):

Check on http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#105568 
"PHP_SAPI" Constant

```
<?php
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')
{
   // ...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but for the record, I see HTTP requests coming in without a User-Agent header and PHP does not automatically define HTTP_USER_AGENT in this case.

Comment: It's already been mentioned in a comment bellow, you can't rely on HTTP_USER_AGENT as it's an optional header.

Comment: Did you downvote my answer and then leave a comment saying the exact same thing I said, Nick?  Nice.  My point, 5 years ago when I left this comment, was to tell the OP that HTTP_USER_AGENT is not reliable.

Comment: Oh wow, obviously I misread it. Reminder not to browse SO while sleepy. Could you please edit your answer a bit so that I can change my vote? Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($argc > 0) {
    // Command line was used
} else {
    // Browser was used
}
```

$argc coounts the amount of arguments passed to the command line.
Simply using php page.php, $argc will return 1

Calling page.php with a browser, $argc will return NULL

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to check whether STDIN is defined:

```
if (!defined("STDIN")) {
    die("Please run me from the console - not from a web-browser!");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check the HTTP_USER_AGENT , it should exist in http request

Comment: There's all sorts of variables in $_SERVER that work under the same idea.

Comment: User agent is optional. I wouldn’t rely on it, since there’s much better solution