# How do I determine whether PHP is running from the console or not?

Tags: php, console, terminal

```
php -f script.php param1 param2
```

At the moment, I am just checking whether `isset($argv)`. Is this the best way?

P.S.
I also wanted to know if all input parameters are always stored in `$argv`?

Comment: Did you even try searching before asking your question? [see accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933367/php-how-to-best-determine-if-the-current-invocation-is-from-cli-or-web-server)

Comment: yes, $argv contains all CLI arguments

Answer (score 1):

As you can read here [Is there any way to know if a php script is running in cli mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607373/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-a-php-script-is-running-in-cli-mode) you can use this function:

```
function is_cli()
{
    return php_sapi_name() === 'cli';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether or not a `REQUEST_METHOD` is set:

```
/**
 * Check if the site is being visited (in a browser) or run as a program from the 
 * commandline.
 * @return boolean true if the request appears to come from the WWW, false if not.
 */
function is_web_request () {
    return isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
}
```