# PHP - how to best determine if the current invocation is from CLI or web server?

Tags: php

I need to determine whether the current invocation of PHP is from the command line (CLI) or from the web server (in my case, Apache with mod_php).

Any recommended methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the canonical way to determine commandline vs. http execution of a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173851/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-determine-commandline-vs-http-execution-of-a-php-s)

Comment: you can use this library: https://github.com/arcanisgk/WEB-CLI-Detector

Answer (score 362, accepted):

`php_sapi_name` is the function you will want to use as it returns a lowercase string of the interface type. In addition, there is the PHP constant `PHP_SAPI`.

Documentation can be found here: http://php.net/php_sapi_name

For example, to determine if PHP is being run from the CLI, you could use this function:

```
function isCommandLineInterface()
{
    return (php_sapi_name() === 'cli');
}
```

Comment: I did a research: if you invoke the script with `php-cgi` this won't work. In turn, it will return `cgi-fcgi` String. If you load the script as a web page from a browser, you'll get `apache2handler`. Hope this helps. I needed to use `php-cgi` in order to introduce `$_GET` variables: `php-cgi myscript.php arg1=one arg2=two`. Testing for not equal to `apache2handler` should be ok for `apache`.

Comment: A small caveat about this method: it will *not* return `"cli"` when run from a cron job. There's a number od differents keys to choose from inside of `$_SERVER` to determine more reliably whether the request came via HTTP or not.

Comment: @omninonsense I tested with PHP 7.2.7 and it returns cli.

Comment: you can use this library: https://github.com/arcanisgk/WEB-CLI-Detector

Comment: I tried this and it sometimes returns `cli` and most of the times `cgi-fcgi`, while the web process always returned `litespeed`. I would try `!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` instead.

Answer (score 52):

I have been using this function for a few years

```
function is_cli()
{
    if ( defined('STDIN') )
    {
        return true;
    }

    if ( php_sapi_name() === 'cli' )
    {
        return true;
    }

    if ( array_key_exists('SHELL', $_ENV) ) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) and !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) and count($_SERVER['argv']) > 0) 
    {
        return true;
    } 

    if ( !array_key_exists('REQUEST_METHOD', $_SERVER) )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This function worked in my case, not php_sapi_name(), since I needed to distinguish between web requests and cronjob executions, and the php_sapi_name() result was "php-cgi" in both cases.

Comment: Can I trust all these variables or is there a possibility a web user could spoof one of those in order to get access that should be limited to users on CLI?

Answer (score 39):

`php_sapi_name()` is really not the best way to perform this check because it depends on checking against many possible values. The php-cgi binary can be called from the command line, from a shell script or as a cron job and (in most cases) these should also be treated as 'cli' but `php_sapi_name()` will return different values for these (note that this isn't the case with the plain version of PHP but you want your code to work anywhere, right?). Not to mention that next year there may be new ways to use PHP that we can't possibly know now. I'd rather not think about it when all I care about is weather I should wrap my output in HTML or not.

Fortunately, PHP has a way to check for this specifically. Just use [`http_response_code()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.http-response-code.php) without any parameters and it'll return TRUE if ran from a web server type environment and FALSE if ran from a CLI type environment. Here is the code:

```
$is_web=http_response_code()!==FALSE;
```

This will even work if you accidentally(?) set a response code from a script running from the CLI (or something like the CLI) before you call this.

Comment: This question was already old when I answered it. Up-voting this answer would've probably been more useful than posting another answer that is a duplicate except without the explanation.

Comment: Regarding "This will even work if you accidentally(?) set a response code from a script running from the CLI ([...]) before you call this.": (at least) as of PHP 7.4.3, this is not true. `http_response_code()` sets code/returns set code when running from CLI. Verified by `<?php function t() { echo var_export(http_response_code(), true) . ' -> ' . (http_response_code() !== false ? 'web' : 'cli') . "\n"; } t(); http_response_code(200); t(); http_response_code(false); t();`. So if `http_response_code()===false` then it`s a safe bet to assume CLI, but if not you need to check also other metrics.

Answer (score 25):

I think he means if PHP CLI is being invoked or if it is a response from a web request. The best way would be to use `php_sapi_name()` which if it was running a web request would echo Apache if that is what it was running.

To list of a few taken from the php [docs on `php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php):

- aolserver
- apache
- apache2filter
- apache2handler
- caudium
- cgi (until PHP 5.3)
- cgi-fcgi
- cli
- cli-server ([Built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) as of PHP 5.4)
- continuity
- embed
- fpm-fcgi
- isapi
- litespeed
- milter
- nsapi
- phttpd
- pi3web
- roxen
- thttpd
- tux
- webjames

Answer (score 13):

This should handle all the cases (including php-cgi)

```
return (php_sapi_name() === 'cli' OR defined('STDIN'));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
function is_cli() {
    return !http_response_code();
}
```

example:

```
if (is_cli()) {
    echo 'command line';
} else {
    echo 'browser';
}
```

Comment: From the manual, "FALSE will be returned if response_code is not provided and it is not invoked in a web server environment (such as from a CLI application). TRUE will be returned if response_code is provided and it is not invoked in a web server environment (but only when no previous response status has been set)". You've gotten your logic backwards.

Comment: +1. Amazing. After so many years of fruitless research... I hereby award you the Nobel Memorial Prize in PHPics, shared with @krowe2 for his invaluable contribution of actually making it work. Congratulations!

Comment: It's possible that something may have set the response code...  `http_response_code(200);`...    if I now call `http_response_code()` it will return 200;

Comment: @BradKent That is ONLY if you call this from a web environment and, in that case, this check is still going to work as long as you didn't set the status code to zero (which is an invalid HTTP status code anyway). My version will work even even in that case because it checks against FALSE specifically. If `http_response_code();` is called from a CLI environment it will always return FALSE regardless of the actual status code. I've already explained this in my answer but you could've also found this out by reading the manual page under "Return Values" or by trying it.

Comment: @krowe2   `php -r 'http_response_code(200); echo http_response_code()."\n";'`  outputs "200"  Unless you can guarantee that some library or ignorant framework hasn't set the response code with `http_response_code` (even in a cli env), then this will work.   Personally, I use `$isCli = \defined('STDIN') || isset($_SERVER['argv']) || \array_key_exists('REQUEST_METHOD', $_SERVER)`

Comment: This also returns `200` when used `php-cgi` in console

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
```

if it's set, you're in a browser.

Alternatlely, you could check if

```
isset($_SERVER['argv'])
```

but that might not be true on windows CLI, IDK.

Comment: Though it is not the "correct" answer it might be the more reliable

Answer (score 3):

I used this:

```
php_sapi_name() == 'cli' || (is_numeric($_SERVER['argc']) && $_SERVER['argc'] > 0)
```

This is from Drush codebase, environment.inc where they have similar check to make.

Comment: If `register_argc_argv` is set, then passing in any amount of GET values will cause `argc` to not be 0.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to check if some of the entries of the [$_SERVER](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) array are set.

E.g.:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        print "HTTP request\n";
} else {
        print "CLI invocation\n";
}
```

Comment: This won't work with `php-cgi` command line, it will set it to `GET` for: `php-cgi -f file.php arg1=2`

Comment: @sebastian, it works with php 8.0.9 on windows though.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php There are a number of constants set only when running from the CLI. These constants are STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR. Testing for one of those will tell you if it is in cli mode

Answer (score 2):

joomla way

```
if (array_key_exists('REQUEST_METHOD', $_SERVER)) die();
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to interrogate the `$argv` variable, (Which you will probably do for command line parameters anyway). Even if there are no parameters `$argv` returns an empty array.

If it is set, then cli was used. You may then assume all other invocations are via some web server or other.

eg:

```
if (isset($argv)) {
  // Do the cli thing.
}
```

Comment: You should not check for $argv because the php-ini defines if it is created or not (only on commandline it is ALWAYS on, but it also can be activated on webserver)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this question depends on the real intent behind it:

- Is the SAPI the deciding factor (web-context or not)?
- Or is the information interpreted as 'running in a tty'?

If the former the answers given and comments written are enough to find a solution that works.

If the latter, the recipes given here will fail if the tool is run as cronjob, or as background-job from another daemon -- in that case I suggest to further test if `STDIN` is a TTY:

```
function at_tty() {
    return defined("\STDIN") && posix_isatty(\STDIN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How, so many complicated solutions. How about ...

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']=="http" or $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']=="https"){
    // must be browser :)
}
```

Comment: "There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here." (https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
You cannot guarantee that REQUEST_SCHEME will be present. So your method could have false negatives for testing if it's a web request.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Detect CLI calls
define("IS_CLI_CALL",( strcmp(php_sapi_name(),'cli') == 0 ));

if(IS_CLI_CALL){
   //do you stuff here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off [Silver Moon's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933367/php-how-to-best-determine-if-the-current-invocation-is-from-cli-or-web-server/25967493#25967493), I'm using this function for returning correct linebreaks:

```
/**
* Linebreak function
* @return "/n" if cli, else return <br>
*/
protected static function lb(){

    return (defined('STDIN') || php_sapi_name() === 'cli' || isset($_ENV['SHELL']) ||
    (empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && count($_SERVER['argv']) > 0) ||
    !isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) ? "\n" : "<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A practical hint

The official way (as told by many) is `PHP_SAPI` as a constant, or `php_sapi_name()` as a function, they both return `cli` when you're in a command line situation. They're right.

**But!...**

Consider using `$_SERVER["argv"]` (also `$argv` in most cases) which is `null` when you run in a browser, and an array when you've been called from command line. The advantage of this approach (or using both) is that you can *simulate a terminal run* in a browser, by just giving a (fake) value to the $argv / $_SERVER["argv"] variable. This comes in handy when you test on an outside server (prod, staging, etc) where you typically won't get SSH access.

The best way to do this is keeping in mind whether you may or may not need a CLI simulation, and use both *$argv* and *PHP_SAPI* to coordinate this - e.g. you may need to output an extra `<pre>` tag beforehand if PHP_SAPI is not "cli" but $argv has a value.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research about it. The reliability is paramount, so you may consider additional checks or techniques to ensure the script's context is indeed CLI.
`php_sapi_name()` and `PHP_SAPI` behave similarly across different Server API (SAPI) types, including custom SAPIs, web servers with CGI/FastCGI, PHP-CLI aliases, and PHP-FPM.

To create a function that detects whether your PHP script is running in the Command Line Interface (CLI) and returns consistent results across all web servers, you can use the `$_SERVER` superglobal to check if certain environment variables are set. Here's a function that accomplishes this:

```php
function isCLI() {
    return (php_sapi_name() === 'cli' || defined('STDIN') || (empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && count($_SERVER['argv']) > 0));
}

if (isCLI()) {
    echo "Running from the command line (CLI)";
} else {
    echo "Not running from the command line (not CLI)";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My preferred method:

```
if (array_key_exists('SHELL', $_ENV)) {
  echo "Console invocation";
}
else {
  echo "HTTP invocation";
}
```

Comment: Env variable SHELL only exists on Linux/Unix, so that is no good way to check this

Answer (score -21):

I'd try:

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

Usually webservers are run under a different username, so that should be telling.