# How to differentiate between a CRON job and a human user in PHP?

Tags: php, unix, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - how to best determine if the current invocation is from CLI or web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933367/php-how-to-best-determine-if-the-current-invocation-is-from-cli-or-web-server)

I created a daily CRON job on my hosting server, which runs on UNIX, of course.

I put the following command in:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/myusername/public_html/foo/foo.php
```

And then, as expected, it executed this `foo.php` on a daily basis.

But this `foo.php` contains important information, and I don't want random people (not to be rude) going to `http://www.mywebsite.com/foo/foo.php` and executing the script.

So what can I do to differentiate between the CRON job, and a human user in PHP?

I've recently seen that when the CRON job is executed, no IP address is given (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is empty). But I'm not sure if that's a fluke.

I tried searching for this topic on Google, with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this in the past

```
if (php_sapi_name() != "cli") {
    throw new Exception("someone tried to run this script outside of cli");
}
```

The `php_sapi_name()` function can tell you who's running the script. Here's the doc page: [php_sapi_name](https://www.php.net/php_sapi_name)

Answer (score 3):

You could just put the cron script outside of the web root, say in `/home/myusername/cron`.

Alternatively, if this is not an option due to FTP restrictions, you can add a parameter to the cron script:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/myusername/....../foo.php cron
```

Then check:

```
if( $_SERVER['argv'][0] != "cron") die("This is a cron script, you cannot access it.");
```