# PHP wait for input from command line

Tags: php, command-line

I want to be able to let a PHP program wait for user's input. For example:

1. Script requests authorization code from server (this code will be sent via e-mail)
2. Script waits for user to enter authorization code
3. Script continues

How should I do step 2? (Is it possible?)

Comment: How about read the man page on php cli usage, particularly useful would be this comment -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#94924

Comment: Thanks @Crisp, you can make that an answer.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the answer linked. You could use the code provided by Crisp which involves file handles. Or simply use the readline() function which will prompt for user input: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php  assuming your PHP was compiled with readline support.

Comment: @Gabe the question is maybe not the same, but an answer to this question was given on the other question, which makes closing fair.

Comment: You might use the built-in php function: "readline()", usage: $line = readline("Command: ");

Answer (score 211, accepted):

The php man page for the cli has a [comment here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#94924) detailing a solution, (copied here for anyone else looking)

```
<?php
echo "Are you sure you want to do this?  Type 'yes' to continue: ";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$line = fgets($handle);
if(trim($line) != 'yes'){
    echo "ABORTING!\n";
    exit;
}
fclose($handle);
echo "\n"; 
echo "Thank you, continuing...\n";
?>
```

Comment: Can this be doing loop, that terminates on input?

Comment: @azurinko yes https://gist.github.com/jordan314/f633a58c68a7d923139b891065365133

Comment: might as well just do `$line = trim(fgets($handle))` since 99.9% of the time you wouldn't want the newline in the captured input

Comment: You can use additional check ```if( php_sapi_name() === 'cli' ) { } ``` to determine if the current invocation is from CLI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933367/php-how-to-best-determine-if-the-current-invocation-is-from-cli-or-web-server

Comment: @billynoah but you might want leading / trailing spaces, so maybe `$line = trim(fgets($handle), "\n\r");`?

Comment: @spiral_generator, anything's possible but I'd be hard pressed to think of a situation where leading/trailing spaces from user input are ever something I want.

Comment: Could someone explain why you cannot use `readline()` for this? I'm new to using PHP for cli scripts. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php

Comment: @Hugo: You *should* use `readline()` for this. This is unnecessarily complicated.