# How to insert $date1 and $date2 in a php file

Tags: php, mysql, command-line-interface

I have a mysql and i want to show information between date1 and date2.

I have this code:

```
require("date1.php");
require("date2.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1 and Date between '$data1' and '$data2' ";
```

and in data1.php and data2.php i have

```
<?php
$data1 = "2015-05-05";
?>
```

and

```
   <?php
    $data2 = "2016-05-05";
    ?>
```

My question is how i can read from keyboard the date. I want to can select from my website between what date1 and date2 to show the information.

Comment: Are you doing a command line script?

Comment: Yes. I know in C++ cin>>data1; :) but i don't know how to do this in php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322371/php-wait-for-input-from-command-line

Comment: i tryed with that code but i can't insert text. when i go on the page i get this: "Are you sure you want to do this? Type 'yes' to continue: ABORTING!" and no option to insert yes

Comment: http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

Answer (score 0):

```
require("date1.php");
require("date2.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1 and Date between '{$data1}' and '{$data2}' ";
```

Done!