# readLine is giving me a call for undefined function error

Tags: php

I'm trying to have my php script wait for a person to press enter for debugging reasons.
I tried to use the readline function and gut the following error

> readLine is giving me a call for undefined function error

The PHP documentation said it worked for ver 4, 5, 7

The

```
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
```

gave me the following

```
Current PHP version: 5.6.30L
```

which i believe is version 5.

My test code for `readline`:

```
readline ("ted");
DIE("stop");
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/readline.installation.php

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install php5-readline`

Comment: An alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322371/php-wait-for-input-from-command-line