# Find out what PHP is running on

Tags: php, apache

I have a script which is running on Apache and also can be executed from command line.

How can i know, on what is php script running, apache or command line?

Comment: Do you run it using command line or access it using a browser?

Comment: Both. I run it on both places.

Comment: See this StackOverflow post, which answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933367/php-how-to-best-determine-if-the-current-invocation-is-from-cli-or-web-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a constant build in PHP that you can use `PHP_SAPI`. If you are on the commandline the value of this constant is `cli` than you are on the command line. Every other value like `cgi`, `cgi-fcgi`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a parameter and only pass it when invoking from the command line?

http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score -3):

Create a page upload it and browse to it.

See page contents below.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```