# Laravel 5.1 - how to split logging based on CGI or CLI?

Tags: laravel, logging, command-line, laravel-5.1

I have Laravel 5.1. It logs CGI (web stuff) with the apache account and that's fine. The problem is if I need to get on there to run an artisan command that I created (that also uses the Log class) it fails because it doesn't have permission to write to the log file that apache created. Is there a way to tell laravel to log to different places based on whether it's via web or cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heading to your config/app.php file you can choose the **Log** driver [according to the executing user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933367/php-how-to-best-determine-if-the-current-invocation-is-from-cli-or-web-server).

**config/app.php**

```
/*...*/
    'log' => php_sapi_name() === 'cli' ? 'syslog' : 'daily',
/*...*/
```

You can also change the [log detail](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors%23logging) level if you want to mute it completely.