# How to make my code run on link

Tags: php

I have php script, I can run this script with php.

But i want make this script without edit the SESSION AND TOKEN and CAN run on browser with link.

So here go:

My script coin.php

I must edit this script to make this code work.

```
$get->session = "MYSESSION";
$get->token = "MYTOKEN";
```

Nah my question is, Can I run this php script WITHOUT edit the php BUT I must edit with LINK

Example: > http://www.example.com/coin.php?session=MYSESSION&token=MYTOKEN

What code should be added on my sript? I want run this script with link

I hope you understand

Thank you so much

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933367/php-how-to-best-determine-if-the-current-invocation-is-from-cli-or-web-server) might help?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I don't think so. I have already read that article

Comment: then please clarify your question, because the most probable interpretation that i can read into it is more than solved by that.

Comment: *"Can I run this php script WITHOUT edit the php BUT I must edit with LINK"* - Kind of like the 'ol *"can't have your cake and eat it too"* bit. *"I hope you understand"* - Actually it seems like I'm not the only one who doesn't. `$_GET` "maybe"? or are you not doing that now?

Comment: Never, *ever*, drink and code.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I want make my code work like this https://sukange.net/index.php Input Id Ig Lo with 12112112 and then fill 1 - 100 whatever you want. And then see the result and run the result. I hope you understand

Comment: ....the plot thickens. Now the question's not only unclear, but too broad.

Comment: just sit down, think the whole thing over and try to word your question in a way so even a pre-schooler would understand it. without any external samples. (and i bet when you get to that point, the solution will be obvious to you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to access: http://www.example.com/coin.php?session=MYSESSION&token=MYTOKEN and use the query string values, your code should be:

```
$get->session = $_GET['session'];
$get->token = $_GET['token'];
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php for further information