# Can I php script know if it's called from command line or web server

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the canonical way to determine commandline vs. http execution of a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173851/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-determine-commandline-vs-http-execution-of-a-php-s)

I am writing a small script that will executed as a cron job. Is there a way to understand if this script is called from a web server so that I could echo `<br />` instead of newline character as output?

Comment: Your best bet is to send a `header('Content-type: text/plain');` and send newline chracters.

Comment: @Truth no, you can determine it definitively by `php_sapi_name()` or `PHP_SAPI`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From php.net

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') 
{ 
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code has been called from the command line, the server variable HTTP_USER_AGENT is not set. Something like this might assist:

```
$newline = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) ? "<br />" : "\n";
```