# What is the most proper way to check if your PHP is run by a Cron job or a HTTP request?

Tags: php, http, cron, request

I'm doing something like this now:

```
if (empty($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
  // the script is run by a Cron job
} else {
  // the script is run by a HTTP request
}
```

Will it go wrong at some situation? More specifically, is $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] always set by Apache? I know some of the variables in $_SERVER like $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] could be tainted by the client side.

Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the canonical way to determine commandline vs. http execution of a PHP script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173851/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-determine-commandline-vs-http-execution-of-a-php-s)

Comment: I tried the suggested answer of using php_sapi_name() for the question but both Cron and HTTP request return the same value of 'cgi'.

Comment: How are you making your cron call? with something like `wget http://blah/script.php` or `php script.php`?

Comment: Then I'm very very surprised that `php_sapi_name` or `PHP_SAPI` are anything other than `cli`

Comment: Just tested. crontab with `*/1 * * * * php /path/to/script.php` outputs `cli` with `php_sapi_name()`.

Comment: Think php_sapi_name() could be depending on server installation. I tested on my server but both output cgi

Answer (score 0):

Try inbuilt php function `php_sapi_name`
It returns the type of interface between web server and PHP

or else, you can use

```
__FILE__   with dirname(__FILE__) or 
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
```

to identify the path name of the current executing php script. 
Store this in a variable, and apply linux `grep` command to verify whether it exists in the cron location `/usr/etc/crontab`

Answer (score 0):

Make two separate scripts would be my first suggestion.

Also $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] depends on the server setup, but should always be set.

From Apache Docs:

> If no ServerName is specified, then the server attempts to deduce the
>   hostname by performing a reverse lookup on the IP address. If no port
>   is specified in the ServerName, then the server will use the port from
>   the incoming request. For optimal reliability and predictability, you
>   should specify an explicit hostname and port using the ServerName
>   directive.

Comment: Hmm... separate script would defeat the purpose of what I'm trying to do.  I'm actually trying to use the HTTP request for the convenience of debugging the script.

Previously I tried changing the script manually to affect only test data during debugging but I find it inconvenient as sometimes I forgot to change it back to the actual script.

Comment: Then maybe have the file in your webroot for debugging and move it out  / remove debugging when switching to a cronjob