# how to determine if php is being run from command line

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the canonical way to determine commandline vs. http execution of a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173851/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-determine-commandline-vs-http-execution-of-a-php-s)

I sometimes run php scripts from command line.  Either with cron or other one time scripts.

I would like to know if its possible within the php script to determine if its being run via command line?

```
<?php

$isRunFromCommandLine = // set to (true:false) -- not sure how to do this

if($isRunFromCommandLine){
  echo 'You are running from command line';
}
else{
  echo 'You are not running php via command line'
}

?>
```

Comment: You are right, it is duplicated.  My initial search did not find it.  I dont think its titled very well? thanks for the link +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if its possible within the php script to determine if its being run via command line?

Definitely. Check for the output of [php_sapi_name](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)( ), it will tell you whether or not you're running in CLI mode.

```
$cli = php_sapi_name( ) === 'cli';
var_dump( $cli );
```

Comment: I suggest this is NOT the best way, see the docs on php_sapi_name() and you'll see it can vary widely.  The Magento `Mage_Shell_Abstract` class uses the variable: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` - if present, the script is being run in a browser, otherwise it's a CLI.

Answer (score 1):

if the script is running via browse the variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` will set and if it's vai terminal it will not set

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
   echo "Via browse";
}
else{
   echo "Via terminal";
}
```