# Detect if request service is accessible in Symfony 2?

Tags: session, symfony, request, locale, symfony-2.1

Function `getCurrentOrDefaultLocale()`, defined in my service, may be invoked from a controller or through a command line script.

Accessing `request` service from CLI throws an exception, and I'm using it to detect the CLI invocation. However catching an exception only for this purpose seems so bad to me.

Is there any reliable way to check if request is accessible in the currenct context (of execution, browser vs CLI)?

```php
/**
 * @return string
 */
protected function getCurrentOrDefaultLocale()
{
    try {
        $request = $this->container->get('request');
    }
    catch(InactiveScopeException $exception) {
        return $this->container->getParameter('kernel.default_locale');
    }

    // With Symfony < 2.1.0 current locale is stored in the session
    if(version_compare($this->sfVersion, '2.1.0', '<')) {
        return $this->container->get('session')->getLocale();
    }

    // Symfony >= 2.1.0 current locale from the request
    return $request->getLocale();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173851/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-determine-commandline-vs-http-execution-of-a-php-s

Answer (score 8):

You could simply check whether current container instance has `request` service/scope using [`ContainerInterface::has()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerInterface.php#L72)/[`ContainerInterface::hasScope()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerInterface.php#L144).

#### EDIT:

My mistake. You have to use [`ContainerInterface::isScopeActive()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerInterface.html#method_isScopeActive), to determine whether `request` service is fully functional:

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, RouterInterface $router) {
    if ($container->isScopeActive('request')) {
        $this->request = $container->get('request');
        $this->router = $router;
    }
}
```

This code snipped is from my own project, where I've experienced a very similar issue.

Comment: Its not working... Im not sure if i do it right, can you provide an example please?