# How to check if a YII app is running from a console or from browser?

Tags: yii

I'm new to YII framework and i'd like to know if there's way to know/check if you are running from console or in a browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same way you would determine if a PHP application is being run in the console or not.

[What is the canonical way to determine commandline vs. http execution of a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173851/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-determine-commandline-vs-http-execution-of-a-php-s)

Comment: Thanks, i thought there's a "YII-specific" function that i'm not aware of. Thanks again.

Answer (score 16):

This reply is a bit late but there is a Yii-specific way to do this:

In Yii1 you can do:

```
if (Yii::app() instanceof CConsoleApplication)
```

In Yii2 that would be:

```
 if (Yii::$app instanceof Yii\console\Application)
```

Hope that's useful to someone...

Answer (score 8):

You should also be able to do:

```
echo get_class(Yii::app());
```

which will tell you what type of app you're in ...

Answer (score 2):

check Yii::$app->id

- when running from console Yii::$app->id = 'app-console'
- when running from frontend (browser) Yii::$app->id = 'app-frontend'

Comment: It entirely depends on your configuration file values.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way seems to define in the root file index.php   this line :

```
define ('WEBAPP', true)
```

Later you can check in any point the application

```
if (defined('WEBAPP')) {
 echo "This is webapp";
} else {
  echo "app was launched via console";
}
```

Checked in Yii 1.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if(is_a(Yii::$app,'yii\console\Application'))

for console, and

if(is_a(Yii::$app,'yii\web\Application'))

for web.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30635800/4916039

Answer (score 1):

I am using Yii 1 and I use this function to check

```
public static function isWebRequest()
{
    return Yii::app() instanceof CWebApplication;
}

public static function isConsoleRequest()
{
    return Yii::app() instanceof CConsoleApplication; //!self::isWebRequest();
}
```

I put these functions in a helper(Componenet) Class and I use it as:

```
if(MyRandomHelper::isConsoleRequest())
{
    Email::shoot();
}
```