# How to detect if I am in 'console' mode

Tags: yii2

I am writing an app that runs from the browser. However, some model functions are also called from the Yii2 console. Therefore, I am getting errors when trying to access variables that are set in the GUI.

Is it possible to tell which mode I am in? Is there some environment variable automatically set, or should I just set some session variable in the console app to indicate the state?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use

```
if (Yii::$app instanceof \yii\console\Application)
```

for console, and

```
if (Yii::$app instanceof \yii\web\Application)
```

for web.

Answer (score 25):

Correct variant

```
Yii::$app->request->isConsoleRequest
```

Comment: `isConsoleRequest` is basically a shortcut for `PHP_SAPI === 'cli'`. This may be less flexible than checking `Yii::$app` type. For example for tests run from console you may want to mock web application. `isConsoleRequest` will return `true` even if you have web application. So this is more useful when you want to use PHP CLI features instead of determine which type of app is currently used.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simpler way to figure this out without going through the `Yii` objects

```
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    return;
}
```

...and it works for all PHP scripts
...and it is lighter

Answer (score 2):

By default for console:

```
Yii::$app->id == 'basic-console'
```

And for web application:

```
Yii::$app->id == 'basic'
```

`Yii::$app->id` stores the id of the loaded configuration params. By default for console application it is `'basic-console'` and for web application it is `'basic'` (defined in configuration file)

Comment: The best and flexible check.

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 provides a number of different classes for application's `console` and for those of type `web`. In addition to this division of the mode of operation of the classes, there are also a set of rules governing the organization of the code of the application. The first, fundamental, it is the respect of giving the MVC Model object information, to view the management interface with the user and, finally, to the controller the role of coordination among them. In your case it seems to sense that a piece of code runs in console but referring to classes that provide a Web interface. Probably because in some Model classes were introduced with functions with HTML or other code that should not be there. If you need two separate applications should precisely separate applications that use a type controls

```
yii\console\Controller
```

and another that uses controller type web

```
yii\web\Controller.
```

Obviously Model classes will be common and, thanks to separate controller, be sure to invoke View appropriate to the type of user interface in use. I Hope this could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Works for nginx and apache:

```
function isConsole()
{
    return 'cli' == php_sapi_name() || !array_key_exists('REQUEST_URI', $_SERVER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure PHP:

```
global $argv;
if (empty($argv)) {
  // Browser mode
}
else {
  // Cli mode
}
```