# How to detect if in CLI mode with cgi-fcgi

Tags: php, apache, exec, command-line-interface, fastcgi

`php_sapi_name()` returns `cgi-fcgi` in both CLI and web :(

Is there any reliable way to detect if the script is current running in command line mode when PHP is running with fcgi?

edit: nvm. it turns out I had to run the `php-cli` executable lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `$_SERVER` and the `$_ENV` superglobal arrays.

Try `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or $_SERVER['argc'].

I found a good answer form https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654906/1197702

```
function drupal_is_cli() {
  return (!isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' || (is_numeric($_SERVER['argc']) && $_SERVER['argc'] > 0)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Whether you have a difference:

```
if (defined('PHP_SAPI')) {
  echo PHP_SAPI;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me on this box:
Debian 7, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u7 (cgi-fcgi) & PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u7 (cli)

```
function is_cli() 
{
    return (
        !array_key_exists('SERVER_SOFTWARE', $_SERVER)
        && (php_sapi_name() === 'cli' || !array_key_exists('REMOTE_ADDR', $_SERVER))
    );
}
```