# PHP: Check if script is being ran with sudo or if user is not using `php`

Tags: permissions, php

How to make a check to find whether the script is run with sudo access or not using PHP ?

Answer (score 9):

<sup>Note: this question would probably be more appropriate on Stack Overflow, even though it refers to PHP on Unix & Linux systems (privilege elevation, permissions, etc.).</sup>

You can use PHP's POSIX functions:

- [posix_geteuid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-geteuid.php) to get the effective user ID.
- [posix_getpwuid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php) to get user information from an UID.

Here is a little example:

```
<?php
$userinfo = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
echo "This script runs with " . $userinfo["name"] . "'s privileges.";
?>
```

Testing...

```
$ php myfile.php
This script is run with myuser's privileges.
$ sudo php myfile.php
This script is run with root's privileges.
```

By the way, since root is always UID 0, you could just check `posix_geteuid() == 0`.

Now, if you want to now whether the user is using the CLI (command-line) or going through the web server, have a look at [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173851/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-determine-commandline-vs-http-execution-of-a-php-s) and the [`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/php_sapi_name) function.

<sup>Another note: I'm pretty sure that running PHP scripts as root isn't the best of ideas. You may want to think again about what permissions your script really needs.</sup>

Comment: I don't see an inherent problem with running a php script as root...it is just as risky as a perl or shell script.

Comment: @SailorCire I wouldn't recommend running a shell script as root either. The thing is, I'm pretty sure the PHP script does not require root privileges from start to finish, and I like to believe it's always best not to grant superfluous privileges.

Comment: Fair enough. So I assume your philosophy is to just not use the root account and only do things through sudo?

Comment: @SailorCire Whether you run your script as root, or through `sudo` as root doesn't change a thing, you're still setting EUID 0. Here an more obvious example: if the only thing your script can't do is "write at /path/a", then you shouldn't be granting it full root access just for that. Instead, you should try to adapt your filesystem permissions, and in last resort, set up a more specific `sudo` policy. [Here is a little something you might find interesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

Answer (score 4):

If it's purely about determining whether `sudo` is used, `sudo` puts a number of values in the environment of the command:

```
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/commandname
SUDO_USER=wurtel
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1001
```

These can be checked in php using the `getenv()` function. Of course, combine it with `posix_geteuid()` function to make sure you really do have elevated privileges as anyone can set those values in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in php only? You could chmod the php directory to only be executable by root and this should achieve the same result for you.

```
chmod 700 filename
chmod 700 foldername -R
```

**-R**

The `-R` means recursive, so any file or sub folders will get the same permissions as the parent. Use this with care.

To improve on this more you can create a 'phpadmin' user which can own the files so no other user can execute them besides root and phpadmin.

```
useradd phpadmin
chown phpadmin:phpadmin foldername -R
```

**Warning**

Please be very careful when using the chmod & chown commands. Make sure you are targeting the correct folder and file names before using these commands.

Comment: Yes, always put that warning...we should make that automatic if the command chmod and chown are used in an answer.