# Output progress for console and web applications

Tags: php, logging, architecture, yii2, microservices

I'm writing an yii2 app that is mainly used as an console application. I have components or (micro)services that fetches some data from a server, handle them and save the information I need to db. Of course there are several **for loops** and in these loops I output my current progress with the use of `yii\helpers\Console::updateProgress` or just `echo` to watch the progress and testing output (like *starting with xxx products*). On some events  I log important informations with `Yii::info()` or `Yii::error()` and so on. Normally a cron handling tasks like `pullProductUpdates` or something else and i.

However in some cases I need the method (i.e. `pullProductUpdates`) in my webapplication too. But then there must not be any `echo` command active or `Console::updateProgress` commands.

Of course I don't have problems with the logging methods from Yii because I configured the log targets and they will not echoing something. But I'm uncertain how to handle the `echo` commands...

One way is to check wether `$_SERER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is set or not. In console it will evaluate to `null` so I can warp an `if {} else {}` around. A probably better solution is to write a `log()` or `progress()` method. A trait could be useful?

So how should I design a solution? Is there any pattern for this? Should my services implement an interface like `loggable` or `proressable`? Or use an Logger/ Progress objects and use some kind of DI (dependency injection)? Because I don't want to write those `log()` or `progress()` methods functions more than one time. Besides I can't use a progress function in a webapplication. One reason is I don't know how to to that (if its possible with php here), but this would be another question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As a PHP programmer you *should* be aware of and use the [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/). In this case you should use dependency injection and the [LoggerInterfaces](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md).

For web application you should configure your composition root to use a logger implementation that logs to a file. For console application you should log to the terminal.

The composition root is the place where you configure your Dependency Injection Container (DIC). See more about [Yii DIC here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html).

In order to do that you should be able to switch between these two composition roots by an environment variable or by [php_sapi_name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173851/2575224).